# ¿Cómo debería usar las mayúsculas en el nombre de mi negocio?

Tags: español-neutral, nombres-propios, uso-de-mayúsculas

Tengo una duda en relación con el nombre de mi negocio, mi duda es cómo debería usar las mayúsculas en el mismo.

Tengo varias opciones:

- Swallow Agencia De Viajes
- Swallow Agencia de Viajes
- Swallow Agencia de viajes
- Swallow agencia de viajes

Y otra duda que tengo, ¿cuál debería ser el orden del nombre de mi negocio?

Tengo dos opciones:

- Swallow Agencia De Viajes
- Agencia De Viajes Swallow

Comment: "De" nunca, y  los nombres comunes (como "agencia"), según actúe como nombres propios (son parte del nombre de la empresa , como en  "Agencia de Viajes Swallow") o no, como en "Swallow (agencia de viajes)". Por influencia del inglés, hoy se abusa muchísimo de las mayúsculas y ya a casi nadie le extraña.

Answer (score 2):

Las razones sociales suelen llevar mayúsculas en las palabras de clase abierta (sustantivos, adjetivos, verbos), tanto en el nombre propiamente dicho (en este caso, Swallow) como en el tipo de empresa. Se usan minúsculas en las palabras de clase cerrada (mayormente, preposiciones). Así, quedaría:

- Swallow Agencia de Viajes

o

- Agencia de Viajes Swallow

Otros casos similares:

- La Meridional Compañía de Seguros (o Compañía de Seguros La Meridional)
- Columbus Banco de Inversión (o Banco de Inversión Columbus)

Comment: Qué interesante lo de _clase abierta_ y _clase cerrada_, no conocía el concepto

Comment: @fedorqui En realidad uso la terminología del inglés, *open-class* y *closed-class words*. Creo que en español se habla más de "categorías léxicas" y "categorías funcionales", respectivamente.

Answer (score 0):

Si el nombre de la agencia es "**Swallow**". Entonces el nombre es **"Swallow agencia de viajes"**.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!